# Play Framework: How to use Scala ActionBuilder in Java Controllers

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I need to use encrypted cookies in a Play Framework project with Java Controllers. This is my first time working with Play (I don't know Scala either). I found an example at Lightbend's Tech Hub which uses symmetric encryption to achieve what I need, however, it is written in Scala:

https://github.com/playframework/play-scala-secure-session-example

In this example, at package.scala is defined the Singleton class UserInfoAction which extends ActionBuilder.

Since I am so new at Play and Scala, I don't know if it is possible to use the UserInfoAction class in Java Controllers. If so, I would appreciate any guidance on how to pass the UserRequest[_] argument to the view, like they do at HomeController.scala class:

```
def index = userAction { implicit request: UserRequest[_] =>
Ok(views.html.index(form))
}
```

It might be a very basic problem, but I haven't found any tutorial on how to mix this kind of Scala classes with Java Controllers in a play framework project.

Comment: Which Java Controller do you refer to? As far as I can see, in the link you provide, it's a Scala only project... Do you plan to add another controller written in Java?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to add a controller written in Java to a local copy of this Scala project.